# Was there any use of scoring rules in economics or finance before Hanson published about LMSR?

Tags: behavioral-economics

Scoring rules arose in the field of meteorology, with the seminal paper published in 1950, but I can't find any references to their using in economics or finance until Hanson published in 2002. Half a century is a long time, so it seems unlikely that Hanson was the first to use scoring rules.

Is the problem just with my Google-fu or was Hanson actually the first? I'm betting on the former.

Comment: Please define and describe "scoring rules" and "LMSR", and their application to Economics, for the benefit of all users. Literature references would also help. Thank you.

Comment: What are "scoring rules?" What are they meant to score?

Comment: Don't have time now, but I will tonight. thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Tom, for now, all I have time for is to give you the link to Wikidedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule

Answer (score 2):

Hanson wasn't the first one.

["Scoring rules and the evaluation of probability assessors"](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1969.10501037) by Winkler was published in the *Journal of the American Statistical Association* in 1969 wasn't published in an economics journal but already mentioned economic applications.

Other examples (probably also not the first publications in economics journals, but still earlier than Hanson) are:

Selten (1991), ["Properties of a Measure of Predictive Success?"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0165489691900764) in *Mathematical Social Sciences*.

Selten (1998), ["Axiomatic characterization of the quadratic scoring rule"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01426214) in *Experimental Economics*.